# Openshift - timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod

Tags: openshift

I'm having some difficulties deploying an Openshift template, specifically with attaching a persistent volume. The template is meant to deploy Jira and a MYSQL database for persistence. I have the following persistent volume configuration deployed:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysqlpv0003 
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi 
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  nfs: 
    path: /var/nfs/mysql
    server: 192.168.0.171
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

Where 192.168.0.171 is a valid, working nfs server. My aim is to use this persistent volume as storage for the MYSQL server. The template I'm trying to deploy is as follows:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
labels:
  app: jira-persistent
  template: jira-persistent
message: |-
  The following service(s) have been created in your project: ${NAME}, ${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}.
metadata:
  annotations:
    description: Deploys an instance of Jira, backed by a mysql database
    iconClass: icon-perl
    openshift.io/display-name: Jira + Mysql
    openshift.io/documentation-url: https://github.com/sclorg/dancer-ex
    openshift.io/long-description: Deploys an instance of Jira, backed by a mysql database
    openshift.io/provider-display-name: ABXY Games, Inc.
    openshift.io/support-url: abxygames.com
    tags: quickstart,JIRA
    template.openshift.io/bindable: 'false'
  name: jira-persistent


objects:
# Database secrets
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: "${NAME}"
  stringData:
    database-password: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
    database-user: "${DATABASE_USER}"
    keybase: "${SECRET_KEY_BASE}"

# application service
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Exposes and load balances the application pods
      service.alpha.openshift.io/dependencies: '[{"name": "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}",
        "kind": "Service"}]'
    name: "${NAME}"
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: web
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
      name: "${NAME}"

# application route
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Route
  metadata:
    name: "${NAME}"
  spec:
    host: "${APPLICATION_DOMAIN}"
    to:
      kind: Service
      name: "${NAME}"

# application image
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ImageStream
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Keeps track of changes in the application image
    name: "${NAME}"

# Application buildconfig
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: BuildConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Defines how to build the application
      template.alpha.openshift.io/wait-for-ready: 'true'
    name: "${NAME}"
  spec:
    output:
      to:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: "${NAME}:latest"
    source:
      contextDir: "${CONTEXT_DIR}"
      git:
        ref: "${SOURCE_REPOSITORY_REF}"
        uri: "${SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL}"
      type: Git
    strategy:
      dockerStrategy:
        env:
        - name: CPAN_MIRROR
          value: "${CPAN_MIRROR}"
        dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
      type: Source
    triggers:
    - type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange
    - github:
        secret: "${GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET}"
      type: GitHub

# application deployConfig
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Defines how to deploy the application server
      template.alpha.openshift.io/wait-for-ready: 'true'
    name: "${NAME}"
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      name: "${NAME}"
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: "${NAME}"
        name: "${NAME}"
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME
            value: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-user
                name: "${NAME}"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-password
                name: "${NAME}"
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
          - name: SECRET_KEY_BASE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: keybase
                name: "${NAME}"
          - name: PERL_APACHE2_RELOAD
            value: "${PERL_APACHE2_RELOAD}"
          image: " "
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          name: jira-mysql-persistent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: "/"
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "${MEMORY_LIMIT}"
    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - jira-mysql-persistent
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: "${NAME}:latest"
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange

# database persistentvolumeclaim
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: "${VOLUME_CAPACITY}"

# database service
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Exposes the database server
    name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
  spec:
    ports:
    - name: mysql
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
    selector:
      name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"

# database deployment config
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    annotations:
      description: Defines how to deploy the database
      template.alpha.openshift.io/wait-for-ready: 'true'
    name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
    strategy:
      type: Recreate
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
        name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
      spec:
        containers:
        - env:
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-user
                name: "${NAME}"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: database-password
                name: "${NAME}"
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
          image: " "
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3306
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          name: mysql
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - "/bin/sh"
              - "-i"
              - "-c"
              - MYSQL_PWD='${DATABASE_PASSWORD}' mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u ${DATABASE_USER}
                -D ${DATABASE_NAME} -e 'SELECT 1'
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "${MEMORY_MYSQL_LIMIT}"
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql/data"
            name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}-data"
        volumes:
        - name: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}-data"
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "${DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME}"
    triggers:
    - imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
        - mysql
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: mysql:5.7
          namespace: "${NAMESPACE}"
      type: ImageChange
    - type: ConfigChange

parameters:
- description: The name assigned to all of the frontend objects defined in this template.
  displayName: Name
  name: NAME
  required: true
  value: jira-persistent
- description: The OpenShift Namespace where the ImageStream resides.
  displayName: Namespace
  name: NAMESPACE
  required: true
  value: openshift
- description: Maximum amount of memory the JIRA container can use.
  displayName: Memory Limit
  name: MEMORY_LIMIT
  required: true
  value: 512Mi
- description: Maximum amount of memory the MySQL container can use.
  displayName: Memory Limit (MySQL)
  name: MEMORY_MYSQL_LIMIT
  required: true
  value: 512Mi
- description: Volume space available for data, e.g. 512Mi, 2Gi
  displayName: Volume Capacity
  name: VOLUME_CAPACITY
  required: true
  value: 1Gi
- description: The URL of the repository with your application source code.
  displayName: Git Repository URL
  name: SOURCE_REPOSITORY_URL
  required: true
  value: https://github.com/stpork/jira.git
- description: Set this to a branch name, tag or other ref of your repository if you
    are not using the default branch.
  displayName: Git Reference
  name: SOURCE_REPOSITORY_REF
- description: Set this to the relative path to your project if it is not in the root
    of your repository.
  displayName: Context Directory
  name: CONTEXT_DIR
- description: The exposed hostname that will route to the jira service, if left
    blank a value will be defaulted.
  displayName: Application Hostname
  name: APPLICATION_DOMAIN
  value: ''
- description: Github trigger secret.  A difficult to guess string encoded as part
    of the webhook URL.  Not encrypted.
  displayName: GitHub Webhook Secret
  from: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}"
  generate: expression
  name: GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET
- displayName: Database Service Name
  name: DATABASE_SERVICE_NAME
  required: true
  value: database
- displayName: Database Username
  from: user[A-Z0-9]{3}
  generate: expression
  name: DATABASE_USER
- displayName: Database Password
  from: "[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}"
  generate: expression
  name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
- displayName: Database Name
  name: DATABASE_NAME
  required: true
  value: sampledb
- description: Set this to "true" to enable automatic reloading of modified Perl modules.
  displayName: Perl Module Reload
  name: PERL_APACHE2_RELOAD
  value: ''
- description: Your secret key for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
  displayName: Secret Key
  from: "[a-z0-9]{127}"
  generate: expression
  name: SECRET_KEY_BASE
- description: The custom CPAN mirror URL
  displayName: Custom CPAN Mirror URL
  name: CPAN_MIRROR
  value: ''
```

When run, the deployment for the MYSQL server eventually fails with the following error:

> Unable to mount volumes for pod
>   "database-1-qvv86_test3(54f01c55-6885-11e9-bc42-3a342852673a)":
>   timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod
>   "test3"/"database-1-qvv86". list of unmounted volumes=[database-data
>   default-token-8hjgv]. list of unattached volumes=[database-data
>   default-token-8hjgv]

The persistent volume claim is attaching to the persistent volume successfully, but as far as I can tell the pod is not attaching to that volume. The template is being deployed in a fresh project, and the PV is freshly created and the nfs is empty. I can't see any errors with how the pod is referencing the persistent volume claim. I'm not sure why this error is occurring, but I'm just learning templates and am clearly missing something. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was in my NFS permissions. Here is the working content of my /etc/exports file:

```
/var/nfs        *(rw,root_squash,no_wdelay)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems issue with open shift to attached volume having high number of files. It's not size but file count. Any logging you need to clear to reduce files count. Other option is to stream logs to splunk or any other external source